# Build failed with an exception error

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to run my android app in my real device, when I run it on android studio this error is showing up:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

here is my code for IntroActivity class:

```
package development.assistant.project.s_assistant;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class IntroActivity extends Activity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
    private TextView[] dots;
    private int[] layouts;
    private Button btnSkip, btnNext;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);



        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
        btnSkip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

        layouts = new int[]{
                R.layout.slide1,
                R.layout.slide2,
                R.layout.slide3};

        // adding bottom dots
        addBottomDots(0);

        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);



    }

    public  void btnSkipClick(View v)
    {
        launchHomeScreen();
    }

    public  void btnNextClick(View v)
    {
        // checking for last page
        // if last page home screen will be launched
        int current = getItem(1);
        if (current < layouts.length) {
            // move to next screen
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
        } else {
            launchHomeScreen();
        }
    }


    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            addBottomDots(position);

            // changing the next button text 'NEXT' / 'GOT IT'
            if (position == layouts.length - 1) {
                // last page. make button text to GOT IT
                btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.start));
                btnSkip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                // still pages are left
                btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.next));
                btnSkip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    };


    private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
        dots = new TextView[layouts.length];

        dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i] = new TextView(this);
            dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
            dots[i].setTextSize(35);
            dots[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.activedot));
            dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
        }

        if (dots.length > 0)
            dots[currentPage].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.inactivedots));
    }


    private int getItem(int i) {
        return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
    }

    private void launchHomeScreen() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, AppBase.class));
        finish();
    }

    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


        public ViewPagerAdapter() {

        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
            container.addView(view);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return layouts.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
            return view == obj;
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            View view = (View) object;
            container.removeView(view);
        }
    }

}
```

this is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "development.assistant.project.s_assistant"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'

}

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    google()
}
```

Comment: add your code here, so that people can help you out

Comment: you said this is occurring on the emulator. what about a physical device?

Comment: this error is occurring in android studio consle, the app could not be installed in the physical device because of this run time error

Comment: The exception does not seem to be due to the Activity. Can you paste the build.gradle file and the entire build log when you get the exception?

Comment: By reading the exception it seems to be some error related to JSON where it was expecting a JSON array but ended up getting a String instead. Anything to do with JSON anywhere in your project?

Comment: Also, can you try and disable the Instant Run feature in Android Studio and try to build your app and check if any errors occur?

Comment: I tried to disable the instant run feature and the same error is showing up